# Documenting PMP Experience

Tags: documentation, pmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I apply for PMP without experiences in all processes? What are the requirements for obtaining these certifications?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/can-i-apply-for-pmp-without-experiences-in-all-processes-what-are-the-requireme)

I am a new member here and getting ready to take my PMP exam. 
I worked as Project Leader reporting it to a project manager for a durability test for a chemical plant. The test lasted for 2 years totaling 10,000 hours of testing. 
Biggest phase in the project was executing and monitoring. 
I have similar experience with other testings as well. Can this monitoring phase be reported on my experience. Because two projects would total it to more than 3500 hours, required for the PMP eligibility.

I would appreciate your thoughts

Comment: Asking anyone other than PMI about what qualifies for credit with them will be anecdotal, and therefore Not Constructive. Voting to close; even if closed, you are certainly welcome to edit the question to make it less of an opinion poll, at which point it could be re-opened.

Comment: Hi Raama, welcome to PMSE! As mentioned by @CodeGnome, it's hard to fit this question in the Q&A format we expect from the questions we have here. Check our [faq]. Besides, there are some similar questions you may find useful (albeit closed) when checking the [tag:pmi] tag. For now, your question seems to be a dup of http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/can-i-apply-for-pmp-without-experiences-in-all-processes-what-are-the-requireme and therefore will be closed. Feel free to change it to make it more objective and exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **You can only claim the hours that you worked on the project.** I may be misunderstanding your comment about testing hours, but 10000 hours / 2 years / 52 wks per year / 7 days per week = 13 hours of work for you per day everyday for two years without a holiday = PMI auditing your claims and denying your application. Be clear about what *your* contribution has been and claim only that.
- **I don't think you can claim hours for different projects over the same period of time.** For example, assume your "big" project ran from Jan 2010 to Jan 2012. From Oct 2009 to Feb 2010 you were also managing a smaller project. From the period Jan 2010 to Feb 2010 you would have to choose which of the two projects you were claiming hours for.
- **You don't have to claim all the hours you worked on a project.** Following on the first bullet, one could reasonably expect say 1100-1200 hours claimed per year if you are employed as a full-time PM. So if you've been in the position for more than about 3 years you could claim bits & pieces of projects so that you can cover off all phases of a project (initiation, planning, control, execution, closure)
- **Be sure that you have appropriate references/documentation to back up your assertions.** PMI could audit your claims. There has been some scuttlebut (e.g. I think on LinkedIn) that PMI is increasing the ratio of claims that are audited.

Comment: Dough - you are right the Durability test was for 10k hours however I worked only 8 hours a day and rest of the time it was unattended. Also I had specific tasks to accomplish during those 8 hours a day. with my PTO and holiday time off i would say 40*46 = 1840 hours per year. Thanks for straightening my thinking. I have 9 years of experience however can not sure first 3 years because the company was sold out and I am not in touch with managers there.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that Doug B posted a very insightful and accurate statement. I recently had my application approved - and Doug is right on with his assessment.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar situation, and was able to claim the hours. PMI selected me for random audit and approved my application.  I was able to document that the work I performed was similar in nature to the monitoring and control processes of Project Management.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. if its not too much trouble can you post how you wrote the job description and accomplishments so that I can compare. if its proprietary work then I can understand and would not ask you to do so.

Comment: Most of it is sensitive; I will try to go back into my archives and find my writeup, but I can't promise it will be as quick.  I also suspect that you'll do just as well. The chief obstacle is framing the question; you've done that, so the rest is implementation.