# Recording work experience on PMP application

Tags: time-management, pmp

can I have 0 hours recorded for some process groups in my PMP application? as I was not involved in all the process groups.

Comment: Related: http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/6603/34

Answer (score 2):

This is what mentioned in PMI handbook.  Here is the link for PMI site. http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Project-Management-Professional-PMP.aspx

> **PMP Eligibility Requirements**
>
> To be eligible for the PMP credential, you must meet certain educational and professional experience requirements. All project management experience must have been accrued within the last eight consecutive years prior to your application submission.
>
> **Educational Background**
>
> - Secondary degree (high school diploma, associate’s degree or global equivalent) **OR**
> - Four-year degree (bachelor’s degree or global equivalent)
>
> **Project Management Experience**
>
> Minimum five years/60 months unique non- overlapping professional project management experience
>   during which at least 7,500 hours were spent leading and directing the project*
>
> **OR**
>
> Minimum three years/36 months unique non-overlapping professional project management experience
>   during which at least 4,500 hours were spent leading and directing the project*
>
> **Project Management Education**
>
> - 35 contact hours of formal education
>
> *Leading and directing the project as identified with the tasks, knowledge, and skills specific in the Project Management Professional Examination Content Outline.
>
> You should have experience in all five process groups across all your project management experience submitted on the application. **However, on a single project, you do not need to have experience in all five process groups.**

**Source: [pmi.org PMP Handbook](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/~/media/PDF/Certifications/pdc_pmphandbook.ashx)**

Comment: One area we might want to improve on this post is clarifying whether the 3 years/36 month requirement can be swapped with the 5 years/60 month requirement when one has a 4 year degree. According to the PMI Handbook, it sounds like the 5 year/60 month requirement is if you have a secondary degree and the 3 year/36 month requirement is for those with the bachelors degree. The way it's presented here, I'm not sure it's clear. Can someone else weigh in?

Comment: I agree - reading this and not knowing the requirements beforehand makes this unclear to me. The Educational Background and Project Management Experience items should be linked in some way

Comment: The PMP handbook sticks them together: Secondary degree ==> 5 yrs/60 mo experience required; 4-year degree ==> 3 yrs / 36 mo experience required.

Answer (score 1):

Since PMP candidates should demonstrate experience in "Leading and directing the project", it is indeed required to have experience in all five process groups. But, as quoted correctly by Sreedhar, you do not have to demonstrate experience in all Five process groups for each individual project you add to your experience list. Only the total matters.