# How to show the PMI Organization that I worked for one year and for more than 1500 hours? What kind of proof and documents do they want?

Tags: pmi-framework, capm

I worked as project coordinator (for the first time) in an oil and gas company.
In the beginning, when I met the project manager who interviewed me for the job, I told him I don't have any experience in the field but that my background will allow me to learn it faster. I mentioned I need to have some training. He said I  would learn the skill on the go.

My job on this project is to  make the environment (the field / site  where the drilling work take place) ready by making sure the needed materials, people (personnel), vehicles, equipment, catering, accommodation are all available throughout the project duration.

I want to obtain the CAPM certificate.

How can I show the PMI organization that I worked for one year and for more than  1500 hours? What kind of proof and documents do they need to pass the audit stage to be qualified to take the exam?

Comment: See page 8 of http://www.pmi.org/Certification/~/media/PDF/Certifications/pdc_capmhandbook.ashx for CAPM requirements.

Comment: As written, this is a question asking for career advice that would apply only to you, rather than allowing for a canonical answer that might also apply to other people. If the question is placed on hold, please edit your question in accordance with our [help center](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help) and it may be re-opened.

Comment: @CodeGnome - I edited a bit to make this easier to read. I feel like the user is asking how to prove he met the requirements, not what the requirements are. Page 8 suggests documenting the project and how much work was done in the 5 categories, but it doesn't address the proof part. I was going to close as a dup of [this post](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/can-i-apply-for-pmp-without-experiences-in-all-processes-what-are-the-requireme), but I'm not convinced it's a duplicate. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: If you get audited, they may want to speak to someone in authority that can back up your claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my PMP I built a spreadsheet that showed the projects I had worked on, the dates, and the allocation of hours by phase.  The proportion of hours was estimated, but defensible.

That was sufficient evidence to pass my audit.

Comment: That's what I am looking for , thank you brother Mark Wallace for the advice , I am going to do the same from the start since I left the old company that  I used to work with . I am now working in a new company with the same role as project coordinator ..